# avc: denied default_android_hwservice, violet neverallow

Tags: android-source, selinux

First I got logs as:

```
11-11 11:11:14.779  2287  2287 E SELinux : **avc:  denied**  { add } for interface=vendor.abc.wifi.wifidiagnostic::IWifiDiagnostic sid=u:r:wifidiagnostic:s0 pid=2838 scontext=u:r:wifidiagnostic:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:**default_android_hwservice**:s0 tclass=hwservice_manager permissive=1
11-11 11:11:14.781  2838  2838 I ServiceManagement: Registered vendor.abc.wifi.wifidiagnostic@1.0::IWifiDiagnostic/default (start delay of 128ms)
11-11 11:11:14.781  2838  2838 I ServiceManagement: Removing namespace from process name vendor.abc.wifi.wifidiagnostic@1.0-service to wifidiagnostic@1.0-service.
```

But if I add

```
allow wifidiagnostic default_android_hwservice:hwservice_manager {add}
```

Get compile error:

```
libsepol.report_failure: neverallow on line 511 of system/sepolicy/public/domain.te (or line 11982 of policy.conf) violated by allow wifidiagnostic default_android_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
libsepol.check_assertions: **1 neverallow failures occurred**
Error while expanding policy
```

How can I resolve it?

wifidiagnostic is a native service which do diagnostic feature. I define the type in wifidiagnostic.te

```
# wifidiagnostic service
type wifidiagnostic, domain;
type wifidiagnostic_exec, exec_type, file_type, vendor_file_type;

init_daemon_domain(wifidiagnostic)

allow wifidiagnostic hwservicemanager_prop:file { getattr map open read };
allow wifidiagnostic hwservicemanager:binder { call transfer };
#allow wifidiagnostic default_android_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
allow wifidiagnostic hidl_base_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
```

and add lable in file_contexts

`/vendor/bin/hw/vendor.abc.wifi.wifidiagnostic@1.0-service u:object_r:wifidiagnostic_exec:s0`

Comment: What is it what you are trying to do? Is `wifidiagnostic` the SELinux type of your HAL? Have you already made corresponding changes to SELinux context files? Please provide more information.

Comment: wifidiagnostic is a native service which do diagnostic feature.

I define the type in wifidiagnostic.te

# wifidiagnostic service
type wifidiagnostic, domain;
type wifidiagnostic_exec, exec_type, file_type, vendor_file_type;

init_daemon_domain(wifidiagnostic)

allow wifidiagnostic hwservicemanager_prop:file { getattr map open read };
allow wifidiagnostic hwservicemanager:binder { call transfer };
#allow wifidiagnostic default_android_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };
allow wifidiagnostic hidl_base_hwservice:hwservice_manager { add };

Comment: and add lable in file_contexts
/vendor/bin/hw/vendor.abc.wifi.wifidiagnostic@1.0-service u:object_r:wifidiagnostic_exec:s0

Answer (score 3):

You should also define your service type

Try following

```
# hwservice_contexts
vendor.abc.wifi.wifidiagnostic::IWifiDiagnostic u:object_r:vendor_abc_wifi_wifidiagnostic_hwservice:s0

# wifidiagnostic.te
type vendor_abc_wifi_wifidiagnostic_hwservice, hwservice_manager_type; 
add_hwservice(wifidiagnostic, vendor_abc_wifi_wifidiagnostic_hwservice)
```

Answer (score 1):

To allow a service to access a HAL you can use the `hal_client_domain()` macro (defined in [system/sepolicy/public/te_macros](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android10-release:system/sepolicy/public/te_macros;l=245)).

I cannot tell from your description what your hal type is. Allowing access to the wifi HAL would look like this:

```
type wifidiagnostic, domain;
type wifidiagnostic_exec, exec_type, file_type, vendor_file_type;

# Allow context switch from init to wifidiagnostic.
init_daemon_domain(wifidiagnostic)

# Allow accessing wifi HAL.
hal_client_domain(wifidiagnostic, hal_wifi_hwservice)
```